# How do I filter a multidimensional NSArray without any keys in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, multidimensional-array, nsarray

So I have the following JSON stored in a multidimensional NSArray:

```
[
      [
            ["First", "Mr Smith", 1],
            ["Second", "Mr Thomas", 0],
            ["Third", "Mr Man", 0],
            ["Fourth", "Mrs Man", 1],
      ],
      [
            ["Fifth", "Mr Johnson", 0],
            ["Sixth", "Mr Mr", 1],
            ["Seventh", "Mr Sir", 1],
      ]
]
```

In Objective-C (for testing)

```
NSArray *json = @[
                  @[
                      @[@"First", @"Mr Smith", @(1)],
                      @[@"Second", @"Mr Thomas", @(0)],
                      @[@"Third", @"Mr Man", @(0)],
                      @[@"Fourth", @"Mrs Man", @(1)],
                      ],
                  @[
                      @[@"Fifth", @"Mr Johnson", @(0)],
                      @[@"Sixth", @"Mr Mr", @(1)],
                      @[@"Seventh", @"Mr Sir", @(1)],
                      ]
                  ];
```

I want to create another array containing just the elements that have 1 as their final value.
I have been sat here for hours trying every different predicate advice I can find online but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a predicate. Write some simple code to iterate the array of arrays pulling out what you need.

Comment: Write code, examine each entry, see if it passes the test.

Comment: I was hoping a more elegant solution existed but I suppose a couple of loops should do the trick.

Comment: I find writing software to be quite elegant, when done properly.  And I find that many supposedly "elegant solutions", using some sort of do-it-all-for-me facility, are longer, uglier, slower, and harder to understand than simply writing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSPredicate` for filtering the array and try like this:-

```
NSMutableArray *mutArr=[NSMutableArray array];
for (NSArray *jsonArr in json)
{
NSArray *filterArr=[jsonArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                          [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                                @"SELF CONTAINS[CD] %@",@1]];
[mutArr addObject:filterArr];
}
NSLog(@"%@",mutArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* validArrayObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSArray* arrayOfArrays in arrayOfArrayObjects)
{
    for(NSArray* arrayOfObjects in arrayOfArrays)
    {
        id obj = [array lastObject];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
            NSNumber *num = (NSNumber *)obj;
            if ([num isEqualToNumber:@(1)]) {
                [validArrays addObject:array];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This goes through all your JSON objects (assuming you already parsed of course) and then checks the last index in each array object to see if its 1. If it is, add it to the valid objects array.

Comment: There are many syntax errors in this code. Plus, The OP has an array of arrays of arrays. Your code is missing a level.

Comment: Yes Im editing as I refresh. Ive been so used to swift lol. Ill clean it up

Comment: You can't compare the two numbers as you do.

Comment: @Aggressor - you should look into `NSPredicate`, it'll simplify your code and is the easiest way to filter arrays

Comment: Where is the variable `array` coming from?